# Using Flash Player in Windows HTML5 app

Tags: html, internet-explorer, windows-8, windows-8.1, flash

While looking over the Adobe Flash Player/AIR Roadmap (found [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/whitepapers/roadmap.html)) I saw this:

"Flash Player release and debug players are available and supported for Windows 8 Desktop and Modern UI experiences on both x86/64 and ARM platforms."

Which got me thinking about a potential method that apps for Windows 8 might be able to be released using Flash Player.

Currently, using AIR, you can build apps for Android and iOS, as well as for Windows Desktop. But Windows 8 Modern UI and Windows Phone 8 are both unsupported platforms.

So the idea was this. If IE 10 for Modern UI supports Flash Player, and if HTML5 Modern UI Windows apps use IE under the hood in order to run, then supposedly you could wrap a Flash Player app inside of an HTML5 app, and then, voilà, you'd have a Windows Modern UI app running off of ActionScript. (Though it still wouldn't work for Windows Phone 8.)

Well, I have tested this, and (sadly) it doesn't work. I would almost bet that this isn't because the functionality isn't there, but rather it is because of some switch on the backend that prevents this functionality from being used.

So, finally, here is my question, mainly to sate my curiosity on the subject. Does anyone know whether or not such a backend switch exists, and if so, is there a way to switch it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the same thing as you and no, I don't think such a switch exists. 
I can only assume Microsoft has purposely blocked off ActiveX controls on purpose, since Silverlight also does not work in HTML5 apps.

It is sort of possible that with Windows 8.1 Update 1, they may change this, but I believe it opens up a lot of problems for them from a security / app store catalogue perspective, so would be unlikely.

Comment: I figured that this might be the case, but I figured that it's worth checking to see what other people might know on the subject. If no one knows any better on this, then I'll accept your answer. But for the time being I'll hold off so as to see what others know.